# What is the CAKEPHP cookie?

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I wonder from which the cookie 'CAKEPHP.
This is automatically generated by CakePHP, but what it is?
[Screenshot of the cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UELzk.png)
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go to the `app/Config/core.php` 
there  have code is

the cookie name is `CAKEPHP`

```
/**
 * The name of CakePHP's session cookie.
 *
 * Note the guidelines for Session names states: "The session name references
 * the session id in cookies and URLs. It should contain only alphanumeric
 * characters."
 * @link http://php.net/session_name
 */
    Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But I change the name of the cookie, then I do not understand why I have another cookie CAKEPHP '.

_Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'cookie' => 'my_cookie',
    'handler' => array(
        'model' => 'Session'
    )
));_

In the HTTP headers, I'm my_cookie, but when I check the browser storage inspector. I also have a cookie CAKEPHP